# Error message about range size conflicts with measurements

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which gets an array from a routine and then wants to write it to a range in a spreadsheet sheet.  I get the following error message when I attempt to write the array to the range.

```
Incorrect range width, was 53 but should be 25 (line 120, file "ScrubRowsFromVolDBSpreadsheet")
```

The script which does the writing is shown below:

```
var cleanedRows=cleanData(source, source_sheet_name,cleanDataSheet);

  var numCleanedRows=cleanedRows.length;

  var numCleanedCols=cleanedRows[0].length;

  Logger.log("numCleanedRows = "+numCleanedRows);

  Logger.log("numCleanedCols = "+numCleanedCols);

  var tempRange=ssOut.getSheetByName("ScrubbedRows").getRange(2,1,numCleanedRows,numCleanedCols);

  Logger.log("tempRangeRows="+tempRange.getHeight());

  Logger.log("tempRangeCols="+tempRange.getWidth());

  //

  tempRange.setValues(cleanedRows);  //// LINE 120
```

The logger entries generated during execution are shown below:

```
[13-10-17 16:43:07:888 PDT] numCleanedRows = 100

[13-10-17 16:43:07:888 PDT] numCleanedCols = 25

[13-10-17 16:43:07:905 PDT] tempRangeRows=100

[13-10-17 16:43:07:906 PDT] tempRangeCols=25
```

What causes this disconnect?  How can I write my array to a range?

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking fhe first row's length. Maybe cleanedRows has some row with more items (columns) ?